# Retrofit 2 How to get created request string before that request is being sent to the server?

Tags: retrofit, retrofit2

I am using httpClient.addInterceptor(logging); to log every requests made before it is being sent to the server. 
But, I have to use those requests to be saved as a string for my generous purpose. If it is possible than how can I implement it?

Comment: Why not look at how the logging interceptor is logging and instead of printing it to log cat, you print it to a file?

Comment: I want to print it to file. I have already go through logging interceptor but didn't get any solution.